# SQL Server Select statement with count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a query to determine if a user is an administrator on my website or not.

I can't quite figure out how to display "True" or "False" after my initial select.

```
select count(*) as IsAdmin 
from UserRoles 
where UserID = '1' and RoleID = 1

IF count is != 0 => True
ELSE False
```

My IF is also not working, probably because I'm writing something incorrectly.
`RoleID=1` means they are administrators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exists in your IF and then proceed with your logic / what you want to return

```
IF(exists(select 1 as IsAdmin from UserRoles where UserID='1' and RoleID = 1))
   SELECT 'IS ADMIN'
ELSE
   SELECT 'IS NOT ADMIN'
```

If in another scenario you were trying to check for a certain number, you can use it as such:

```
IF(select count(*) as IsAdmin from UserRoles where UserID='1' and RoleID = 1) > 0
   SELECT 'IS ADMIN'
ELSE
   SELECT 'IS NOT ADMIN'
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept soon as the timer is up on stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem @AlexP glad to help

Answer (score 1):

```
select (case when UserID = '1' and RoleID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as IsAdmin
from UserRoles
```